# Reconciling the Interface Segregation Principle with the need to uniquely identify an object

Tags: c#, architecture, solid

I have an interface `ICondition` which only defines a single method, `IsConditionMet`

This works well as it is the only information the parent entity needs from its conditions.

However, there is a situation where a user needs to remove a specific condition from its parent that I am struggling to find a elegant way to implement.

Both classes that implement this interface happen to use a GUID identifier at the moment, but there's no inherent reason why this would need to be the case and could be subject to change; the two classes don't really have anything in common other than being predicates.

One possible solution could be to override the `Equals` method in the classes and return true when passed the ID. However, to me, this seems to not quite mesh with the intent of the method and violates the principal of least astonishment.

Another solution could be to create an `IIdentifiable` interface with a method, `IdentifiesAs` then have `ICondition` inherit from it. This however seems like it goes against the ISP spirt as any implementor of `ICondition` must now implement `IIdentifiable` too.

Does anyone have any guidance for sticking to the ISP while being able to uniquely identify a object? Am I overthinking this?

Comment: It seems like you need more than just IsConditionMet() to be usable. add more!

Comment: Do all conditions have an ID?  My experience would lead me to assume they do.  If they all do, what would be so bad about putting `IdentifiesAs`  directly on the `ICondition` interface?

Comment: @MIke actually, there is a third that doesn't (But it's a mock used for unit testing)

Comment: How does the user want to identify the condition? And remove it from where?

Comment: @Goyo Parent.RemoveCondition("ID")

Comment: That suggest me that `Parent` should be responsible of knowing how ids map to conditions. A standard mapping would do, no need to mess with the interface.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer Wait you don't want to call `RemoveCondition` with a hardcoded id do you?

Comment: @Goyo: How else would you do it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey More often than not I do not know the exact value that should be passed to a function so I use a variable that will take the needed value at runtime. Of course a literal could be fine in this case, how could I know?

Comment: @goyo: I presume that is Cat's pseudocode.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that I've understood you, you have a situation where:
1. Currently you have a couple of types that implement `IsConditionMet` and `IdentifiesAs`. 
2. You see a situation where in the future, you may need types that only implement `IsConditionMet`.

Assuming that's correct, then follow the YAGNI (you ain't going to need it) principle: when you need to handle types that only implement `IsConditionMet`, deal with that situation at that time.

However, there is away that you can plan for this, without creating unnecessary code now: good names.

Create an `IIdentifiableCondition` type now:

```
interface IIdentifiableCondition
{
    bool IsConditionMet(...);
    Guid IdentifiesAs { get; }
}
```

Then in the future, when you just need `IsConditionMet`, add a parent interface, thus:

```
interface ICondition
{
    bool IsConditionMet(...);
}


interface IIdentifiableCondition : ICondition
{
    Guid IdentifiesAs { get; }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, though this would still break my unit test where I test the logic associated with parent which has a dependency on a mock `ICondition`, but no need for an ID

Comment: And I dont have any `IdentifiesAs` it is just one possible solution I was putting forward

Answer (score 1):

From the comments to your original post, it is obvious that your `ICondition` has to be qualified by the identifier in some form or other.

```
interface ICondition<ID> {
  ID GetId();
  bool IsConditionMet();
}
```

This abstracts away the nature of the ID, and closes the contract that the `ICondition` must meet: that it both indicate that the condition is met and be able to identify itself for possible removal.